# Perl: How can I split these texts to extract the required info?

Tags: perl, split

**EDITED/Shortened VERSION**

I have two texts, which come from two files that I have to loop through (you can ignore my variables). Here is a sample from each:

**Tagged**:

```
5.4_CD Passive_NNP Processes_NNP of_IN Membrane_NNP Transport_NNP 85_CD We_PRP have_VBP examined_VBN membrane_NN structure_NN and_CC how_WRB it_PRP is_VBZ used_VBN to_TO perform_VB one_CD membrane_NN function_NN :_: the_DT binding_JJ of_IN one_CD cell_NN to_TO another_DT ._.
```

Desired output:

`5.4 Passive Processes of Membrane Transport 85 We have examined membrane stru....`

**Parsed**:

```
   Parsing [sent. 1 len. 31]:
        nsubj(85-7, Processes-3)
        nn(Transport-6, Membrane-5)
        prep_of(Processes-3, Transport-6)
        nsubj(examined-10, We-8)
        nsubjpass(used-17, it-15)
        xsubj(perform-19, it-15)
        conj_and(examined-10, used-17)
        xcomp(used-17, perform-19)
        dobj(perform-19, function-22)
        prep_of(binding-25, cell-28) <- refer to this for examples below
```

Desired output:

- the sent. number (ie. `sent. 1` )
- the grammar function (ie. `prep_of` )
- the first dependency word (ie. `binding` )
- the second dependency word (ie. `cell` )

**QUESTION**

How can I split/substitute these to get my desired output, so that they keep a word boundary on the end and beginning (`=~ \bword\b` should apply)??

THANKS a lot for taking your time to read this! Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  what is the actual question?

Comment: I edited it, first line explains. Basically, sometimes I can't use \b in a regex, and the way I did it is hard to work with (ie. sometimes having to use $array[2]). 

I guess I'm wondering if you are a little more clever/ have more experience than a beginner like myself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have difficulty understanding even your revised question.  Since I have skipped your historical questions due to not understanding what you wanted, I thought I would share a better explanation.  You would be well advised to skip the background material and just break down the problem into:

```
@subsentences = ("5.4_CD Passive_NNP Processes_NNP","85_CD We_PRP have_VBP examined_VBN membrane_NN");
foreach my $sub (@subsentences) {
  @final = split(/_\S+/,$sub);
  print join(",",@final)."\n";
}

Expected output:  ("5.4", "Passive", "Process") and ("85", "We", "have", "examined").
```

The sad thing is, I cannot even tell if my guess about what you might mean in this ONE example is correct (might you have meant `@subsentence = qw(5.4_CD Passive_NNP Processes_NNP)` instead? or something else?).  Repeat for each example.  Assuming I guessed correctly, the regex you want in this example is:

```
@finalsentence = split(/_\S+(?:\s+|$)/,$subsentences[$j])
```

Or the equally valid(?)

```
@finalsentence = grep(s/_\S+//||1,split(/\s+/,$subsentences[$j]));
```

I think we have discovered that the actual question he wanted asked was:

```
@subs = qw(5.4_CD Passive_NNP Processes_NNP);
Expected output: qw(5.4 Passive Processes)
```

If my revised understand is correct, the following will do what you want

```
@subs = qw(5.4_CD Passive_NNP Processes_NNP);
@final = @subs;
grep(s/_\S+//,@final);
print join(",",@final)."\n";
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the question. :) I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @Jon: I revised my answer for my new (possibly still flawed?) understanding of what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Does that grep/join sequence work for all my desired splits or just the sentences?

Comment: @Jon: If what you are trying to do with the splits is run a substitute `s//` over all items in a list one by one, then yes, I recommend using the grep technique (you can also use map) instead of using split in a loop. If you are trying to do something else, I recommend rewriting the question in the style I recommended (small test cases, sample output)